# Using GET to pass arguments to PHP function

Tags: php, forms

Inherited a website that has a calculator form running that broke when host updated server to PHP7.2 from 5.6.  Looking at error logs the issue seems to be with passing the $data to the function correctly.

The error that I am getting is

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function CalculateTitleFee()

It says that it is getting 1 argument but expecting 2.  In my browser I can see the 500 error on the URL that clearly shows 2 values for data.

My initial guess is either that the GET isn't working correctly, or that it isn't building the data into an array correctly.

Here is the PHP in question.

It all starts with:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];

$json_data = array();
$json_data['error_code'] = '0';

// Determine the action that the javascript is attempting to perform
switch ($action) {
    case "display_main_menu":
    case "back":
        $json_data['html'] = display_main_menu();
        break;
    case "display_purchase_example":
        $json_data['html'] = display_purchase_example();
        break;
    case "display_refinance_example":
        $json_data['html'] = display_refinance_example();
        break;
    case "calculate":           
        $post_data = $_GET['data'];

        $json_data['calc_data'] = calculate($post_data);
        break;
}

echo json_encode($json_data);
```

The form is then sending:

```
urltophp.php?action=calculate&data%5B%5D=80000&data%5B%5D=90000
```

Here is the calculate function:

```
function calculate($data) { 

    $calc_data = array();
    $title_premium = CalculateTitleFee(floatval($data[1])) + CalculateLoanPolicy(floatval($data[0]));
    $title_premium_refi = CalculateTitleFeeRefi(floatval($data[0]));
}
```

That function has a lot going on that I didn't copy, but the error is happening CalculateTitleFee() function.  Hoping to resolve that and everything else works correctly.

===== UPDATE =====

Here is the CalculateTitleFee function.

```
function CalculateTitleFee ($purchase_price, $loan_amount){
    $title_premium0 = 0;

    if ($purchase_price <= "100000") {
        $title_premium0 = ((ceil((($purchase_price-30000)*0.00375)+180)-(ceil((($purchase_price-30000)*0.00325)+150)))+100);
    }
    else if ($purchase_price <= "200000") {
        $title_premium0 = ((ceil((($purchase_price-100000)*0.00275)+442.5)-(ceil((($purchase_price-100000)*0.00225)+377.5)))+100);
    }
    else if ($purchase_price <= "300000") {
        $title_premium0 = ((ceil((($purchase_price-200000)*0.002)+717.5)-(ceil((($purchase_price-200000)*0.00175)+602.5)))+100);
    }
    else if ($purchase_price <= "10000000") {
        $title_premium0 = ((ceil((($purchase_price-200000)*0.002)+717.5)-(ceil((($purchase_price-200000)*0.00175)+602.5)))+100);
    }

    return $title_premium0;

    }
```

Comment: `CalculateTitleFee` really is only getting one argument in that `calculate()` function.

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix - results in same error.

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function CalculateTitleFee(), 1 passed in /calculator/calculator.php on line 147 and exactly 2 expected in /calculator/calculator.php:78\nStack trace:\n#0 /calculator/calculator.php(147): CalculateTitleFee(90000)\n#1 /calculator/calculator.php(25): calculate(Array)\n#2 {main}\n thrown in /calculator/calculator.php on line 78, referer: calculator/calculator.html

Comment: well `CalculateTitleFee()` clear takes 2 arguments, you give it one, so um ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not because of `$_GET`. This was always a problem, but only started throwing an exception when you updated to PHP 7. Too few arguments used to cause a warning, [as of PHP 7.1 it causes an error](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible).

In your `calculate()` function, you are calling `CalculateTitleFee` with only one argument.

```
CalculateTitleFee(floatval($data[1]))
```

`CalculateTitleFee()` does take a second argument, but it is never used in the function. It should be safe to remove that parameter from the function definition.

Comment: That makes sense.  However the function was calculating correctly in the past I assume.  I've added that function to my OP.  Hopefully that helps diagnose.  Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out.  By.... looking at the function.... which you said.  Ha!  IDK why it was requiring two variables when it was only using one in the function.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, just updated the answer to say that at the same time :-)

Comment: Maybe the functionality that required that variable was moved into the `CalculateLoanPolicy` function and they forgot to remove the variable? Who knows